# How can I access CLI options passed to test from inside a test suite

Tags: node.js, jestjs, command-line-interface

I have a jest command like this:

```sh
npx jest -c "..." one-big-test-suite test-1
```

Now, I want to access `one-big-test-suite` and `test-1` from test suite `one-big-test-suite.test.ts`. Because jest uses workers to process tests, I am not able to use `process.argv` since it returns:

```js
argv: [
  '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/app/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js'
]
```

Is there a way to access these CLI options using NodeJS or is there a function in Jest that gives me access to either CLI options or just list of test suites that will be running?

Comment: If you explain why do you need to access it, probably you'll be suggested a better solution

Comment: We have one test Suite that creates more than 100 tests (we are using Storybook  Storyshots addon) dynamically; so, we want to be able to execute only specific tests if CLI arguments are passed (e.g if `test-1` CLI  argument is passed, only that test should be generated in the suite and executed by Jest)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best chance it to set environment variables and dynamically skip tests based on that by accessing `process.env`.